# Иконка для приложения в JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, intellij-idea, scene-builder

Хочу заменить стандартную иконку в программе, но при запуске выдает ошибки, подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить. Картинка для иконки 128х128 пикселей, 35.6КБ, расширение .ICO

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.io.IOException;

public class HelloApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
//  Иконка
//  Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("logo_128_128.ico")));
//  Image ico = new Image("resources/Image/logo_128_128.ico"); stage.getIcons().add(ico);
            FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(HelloApplication.class.getResource("hello-view.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load(), 1280, 720);
//  Иконка
            stage.getIcons().add(new Image(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/logo_128_128.ico")));
            stage.setTitle("calculation");
            stage.setScene(scene);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

Comment: "но при запуске выдает ошибки" - добавьте пожалуйста в вопрос тексты ошибок (для этого нажмите [edit])

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я знаю javaFX поддерживает расширения jpeg, png, gif, bmp.
Попробуйте сохранить картинку в одном из них.
Перед ссылкой на картинку добавьте "file:".
Т.е. в общем виде это должно выглядеть так
`Image image = new Image("file:ВАШ_ПУТЬ")`

Comment: не исключаю, но смена формата картинки не помогла, искал по форуму нашел разные варианты, но видно я не совсем правильно это реализовать пытаюсь

Comment: Вообще нет, в целом Вы реализуете классический способ смены картинки. - stage.getIcons().add(new Image("path"). Не зная что за ошибка выскакивает, могу только предполагать, но попробуйте прописать ссылку полностью. И если закоментить строку со сменой иконки программа запускается?

Comment: Напишите, если new Image("file:ВАШ_ПУТЬ") поможет